# Frequency table (percentages) from multi-select questions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I would like to simply my code to get a frequency table. Let's say that I run a large bakery brand company and conduct a customer survey where I ask their purchase history of my products.

I ask whether they have purchased different kinds of products (e.g., cookies, candies, scones, macarons) from my company and where they bought them. I ask them to select all apply.

Q. Have you ever purchased our brand's ____?

- cookies via online
- cookies at a local store
- cookies at a chain store
- candies via online
- candies at a local store
- candies at a chain store....

I have the survey responses in a long dataset:

```
set.seed(2)

record_id<- c(1:1000)
a_method_1 <- sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
b_method_1<-sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
c_method_1<- sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)

  
a_method_2 <- sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
b_method_2<-sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
c_method_2<-   sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)


a_method_3 <- sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
b_method_3<-sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
c_method_3<- sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)


a_method_4 <- sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
b_method_4<-sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)
c_method_4<-   sample(c(1:2), replace = T, size = 1000)

mockdf<- data.frame(record_id, a_method_1, b_method_1, c_method_1,
                    a_method_2, b_method_2, c_method_2, 
                    a_method_3, b_method_3, c_method_3,
                    a_method_4, b_method_4, c_method_4)

set.seed(2)
mockdf<- mockdf %>% mutate(
  across(.cols= (c(2:13)),
         .fns = ~ifelse(rbinom(n(), 1, 0.1), NA, .x))
)  # To make it realistic, adding NAs

mockdf<- mockdf %>% mutate(across(c(2:13), ~factor(.x, levels= c(1,2),
                                                   labels = c("checked", "unchecked"))))

mockdf<- mockdf %>% pivot_longer(c(2:13), names_to = "source_type") %>% mutate(product = case_when(endsWith(source_type, "1")~ "macaron", 
                                                                                         endsWith(source_type, "2")~ "cookie",
                                                                                         endsWith(source_type, "3")~ "scone",
                                                                                         endsWith(source_type, "4")~ "candy",
                                                                                         TRUE~ NA), 
                                                                     method = case_when(startsWith(source_type, "a")~ "online", 
                                                                                        startsWith(source_type, "b")~ "local store", 
                                                                                        startsWith(source_type, "c")~"chain store", 
                                                                                        TRUE~ NA)) %>% select(-source_type)

head (mockdf)
#  record_id value     product method     
#      <int> <fct>     <chr>   <chr>      
#1         1 checked   macaron online     
#2         1 unchecked macaron local store
#3         1 unchecked macaron chain store
#4         1 checked   cookie  online     
#5         1 unchecked cookie  local store
#6         1 checked   cookie  chain store
```

From here, I want to get the frequency table with percentages where the denominator is the # of people who have purchased **each type of product**, instead of the total # of respondents or the # of people who purchased any product.

I can get the table with the code below but it is repetitive and cumbersome, especially when I have many different types of products. How can I simplify this code?

```
n_macaron<- mockdf %>% filter(product == "macaron" & value == "checked") %>% distinct(record_id) %>% nrow()
n_cookie<- mockdf %>% filter(product == "cookie" & value == "checked") %>% distinct(record_id) %>% nrow()
n_scone<- mockdf %>% filter(product == "scone" & value == "checked") %>% distinct(record_id) %>% nrow()
n_candy<- mockdf %>% filter(product == "candy" & value == "checked") %>% distinct(record_id) %>% nrow()

mockdf %>% filter(value == "checked") %>%  group_by(product, method) %>% count() %>% 
  mutate(perc = case_when(product == "macaron"~ round((n/n_macaron)*100,0),
                          product == "cookie"~ round((n/n_cookie)*100,0),
                          product == "scone"~ round((n/n_scone)*100,0),
                          product == "candy"~ round((n/n_candy)*100,0)))
        

# A tibble: 12 × 4
# Groups:   product, method [12]
#   product method          n  perc
#   <chr>   <chr>       <int> <dbl>
# 1 candy   chain store   465    55
# 2 candy   local store   433    51
# 3 candy   online        450    53
# 4 cookie  chain store   469    55
# 5 cookie  local store   470    55
# 6 cookie  online        475    56
# 7 macaron chain store   429    51
# 8 macaron local store   439    53
# 9 macaron online        444    53
#10 scone   chain store   437    53
#11 scone   local store   433    53
#12 scone   online        444    54
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Count by distinct `record_id` and `product`, then join **by product** to the count by `product` and `method`.

```
library(dplyr)

mockdf %>% 
  filter(value == "checked") %>% 
  distinct(record_id, product) %>% 
  count(product, name = "den") %>% 
  right_join(mockdf %>% 
               filter(value == "checked") %>% 
               count(product, method, name = "num")) %>% 
  mutate(perc = round((num / den) * 100, 0))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
   product   den method        num  perc
   <chr>   <int> <chr>       <int> <dbl>
 1 candy     843 chain store   465    55
 2 candy     843 local store   433    51
 3 candy     843 online        450    53
 4 cookie    847 chain store   469    55
 5 cookie    847 local store   470    55
 6 cookie    847 online        475    56
 7 macaron   836 chain store   429    51
 8 macaron   836 local store   439    53
 9 macaron   836 online        444    53
10 scone     821 chain store   437    53
11 scone     821 local store   433    53
12 scone     821 online        444    54
```

I suspect there's a more elegant way to do it, with all calculations in the one data frame.